# Ubuntu 15.04 kernel panic -- not syncing attempted to kill the idle task

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, vmware, kernel

I just purchased a Lenovo W540 workstation with the following specifications: 
CPU i7-4810MQ (quad core)
32 GB RAM
2 TB SSD storage capacity
Nvidia Quadro K1100M 2GB graphics card.
Windows 7 Pro OS

I installed VMware on it so that I can run an Ubuntu 15.05 OS
guest OS under Windows 7. However, when I tried to install Ubuntu 15.04 with either 64 bit or 32 bit capability, I got an error message "Kernel panic -- not syncing: Attempted to kill the idle task". The same happens when I try another Ubuntu version like 14.04.2. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Now I enable VT in the bios of the computer.